# Different variables for same equation

Tags: input

```
a = {25.0,32.0}; k = {100.0,28.0};
P = (1.92*a^(2/3) - 0.02 + 0.8*k^(-3/4));
```

In the second equation (which is P) I want to use a1=25 and k1=100 firstly after calculation with this initial conditions, second values a2=32 and k=28 should be used in the P. How can I do this ?

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica? I ask because that's not a valid Mathematica syntax. If so, have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes this is about Mathematica. You can change the definitions as you want

Comment: I am interested in different inputs for same equation

Comment: Take a look at `Table`. You can also use `Block` or define a function `p[a_, k_]:=...` etc.

Comment: In this case how can I define Inputs ? definition  'a=[25.0,32.0]' is valid ? and why are these people vote  my question negatively?

Comment: @Ttys No downvote from me. But I can imagine that many people expect askers to get in touch with the language's basic syntax before asking.

Comment: because of those minus votes they will ban me, they gave me a warning!!

Comment: Please take a look at [asking guidelines](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS) You should always include a valid WL code (posted code is not valid), show your efforts (not shown). And make sure the question is clear by showing expected result etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {25.0, 32.0}; k = {100.0, 28.0};
P[x_] := (1.92*a[[x]]^(2/3) - 0.02 + 0.8*k[[x]]^(-3/4));

P[1]
P[2]
```

> 16.4211
>   19.3981

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: welcome to Mathematica!

Comment: What if I use P[x] in a different equation ? How can I get two output for different input values ?e.g.  'A=2*P[x]'

Comment: You can make a `Table` like `Table[2*P[n],{n,1,2}]`. This will output the values for 2*P[n]  for n=1 upto n=2.  Add this code after the function P in my code

Comment: I see. table will be useful.

Comment: Mathematica's documentation is very useful. Which version of mathematica are you using?

Comment: version is 11.2